# Git-bash on Windows only recognizes some symlinks

Tags: git-bash

This one has me stumped. I have set these symlinks (using mklink) in a directory that is in my git-bash PATH.

```
[@Pawel-HP2 bin]$
ls -la
lrwxrwxrwx 1 pawel 1049089     46 Nov 19 11:10 np -> /c/Program Files    (x86)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 pawel 1049089     46 Dec 17 09:30 npp -> /c/Program Files     (x86)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 pawel 1049089     80 Dec 16 14:40 pycharm -> /c/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/PyCharm Community Edition 5.0.2/bin/pycharm.exe*
```

Now when I go to some directory on c drive:

```
[@Pawel-HP2 bin]$
cd /c
[@Pawel-HP2 c]$
which np
/c/Users/pawel/Documents/bin/np
[@Pawel-HP2 c]$
which pycharm
/c/Users/pawel/Documents/bin/pycharm
```

Now when I switch to a different drive, it still finds the pycharm link but not the notepad++ link!

```
[@Pawel-HP2 c]$
cd /f
[@Pawel-HP2 f]$
which pycharm
/c/Users/pawel/Documents/bin/pycharm
[@Pawel-HP2 f]$
which np
which: no np in (...)
```

Why the difference in recognizing one but not the other symlink? And in general how to make it find my notepad++ symlink across all drives?